# Implementing SignalR setup using nugets

Tags: signalr, nuget

Which actions should you perform.
(Choose all that apply)

A: Add service connection. //Could it be establish connection?

B: Implment interface: Providers

C: Creating a hub class to push content to clients

D: Register ?

E: Create owin startupclass

Comment: this site is not suitable for giving you exam certification answers, in this case 70-486

Answer (score 1):

C: Create a Hub class (not necessarily only for pushing content, two way communication)

E: You will need the Owin startup class

D?: You need to connect to the hub from your Javascript/.NET client.

[This](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) will help.